# Are "call a taxi (a cab)" and "call for a taxi (a cab)" the same?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, difference

I want to make a question sentence like below:

> *"Is calling a taxi the only way to take a taxi here? (Or from here?)"*

I'm wondering if 'calling for a taxi" would mean the same thing as "calling a taxi". Also, would it have any slight difference if I used 'from here' instead of just 'here' at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Calling a taxi" would sound more like you are talking directly to the taxi, or hailing one in the street. "Calling for a taxi" could mean that you are calling a phone number to speak to someone about arranging a taxi, so it's what you'd want to use here.

You would use "from", as if you just say "here", there is a certain ambiguity, where "here" could represent either the starting point or the destination.

So it would be:

> Is calling for a taxi the only way to take a taxi from here?

The above sounds a bit odd/abstract though; some more direct and descriptive alternatives would be (this might be a bit colloquial as it's just how I would likely say this, but the point is that we are specifying the alternative to calling for a taxi):

> Are there taxis around here or will I need to call for one?
>
> Is there a taxi rank nearby or will I need to call for one?

Comment: This answer may be correct for British English. In Australian English I’d expect “Call a taxi.” not “Call *for* a taxi.”. The second version is possible but not as idiomatic in ordinary conversation. For example, *“We just missed the last tram! Call a taxi.”* or *”I know the meeting’s not quite finished but my flight’s at 5pm. Excuse me while I call a taxi.”*

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the list of answers. I usually hear '[hail a cab](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hail+a+cab)', or 'hail a taxi'.

Comment: But this has a different meaning. You “call a taxi/cab” on your phone. You “hail a taxi/cab” standing at the curb with an arm in the air.

Comment: You call or book a trip? "Taxi Hailing App" is what I know. :)

Comment: Okay we agree as to usage. I just didn’t read the OP as talking about an app. They used “call”.